# Is there a way to store a one (unique) data element in SQLite?

Tags: database, sqlite

I need to use SQLite database file as a file for storing information, and I want to store the version of the file in the SQLite database file.

How can I do this? I mean, how to store unique (only one) data in SQLite? I don't want to use store the info by making table for this, as the version info is just one number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For SQLite, which *is* an *embedded database*, after all, there's nothing wrong with using a single table for holding a unique value like this.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE AppVersion (version);
sqlite> INSERT INTO AppVersion VALUES('1.0');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM AppVersion;
1.0
sqlite> UPDATE AppVersion SET version='1.1';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM AppVersion;
1.1
```

It's an embedded database.  You expect *good* performance when you use it, not *perfect* performance.  A single extra table (holding only a single row ever) shouldn't make *any* difference to any reasonable application.

Comment: I doubt that the OP's concern was about *performance* - he never suggested such. It's more just that using a table to store this information is semantically wrong, potentially misleading to somebody looking at the schema before having seen the application ("So, like, we store all the versions we've ever released in this table?" "Nope, just one of them."), and (to my eyes) ugly. Having a way to explicitly store a *persistent variable*, rather than a *table row*, would be more expressive. But it doesn't exist, so we must make do with the tools we have.

Comment: @MarkAmery Specifying a UNIQUE constraint helps to express that there can only be one value. It doesn't say that there can't be zero values, though.

Comment: @Syncopated I disagree; a UNIQUE constraint doesn't help express anything other than the restriction it actually imposes on the data, which is to forbid duplicate values, not to forbid having multiple distinct values.

Comment: @MarkAmery I guess I was being quite unclear. I meant something like this: `CREATE TABLE AppVersion(version TEXT NOT NULL, enforcer INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL CHECK(enforcer == 0), UNIQUE (enforcer));` Then if you try to do the following twice, the second attempt will fail: `INSERT INTO AppVersion (version) VALUES(1);`

Answer (score 2):

For single data entries I like to use keys to lookup the data in a table, something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "keyedData" (
    "key"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    "data"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("key")
)
```

Comment: While this solves the inherent issue arising from using the DB storage paradigm in an unintended way, it seems like it would also just make it way more inefficient. We are doubling up the amount of work needed to access a variable on our end and probably more under the hood, unless SQLite is doing some very smart optimizations.

This also is way more error prone. Because suddenly you can have the entries:
"version", "ver", "VER", "v", "VERSION" all be different values and you are complexity unaware you are using different keywords every time you try to access your version number.

Comment: I'm sorry but your response doesn't make any sense in my opinion and it feels like it is written by a chatbot.

Comment: The OP asked how to store a version number in a database. The fundamental problem is databases are designed to store columns of data not 1 element.
Your solution is to simply store "version" and "1.03.0" to 2 columns. This would make sense if OP wanted to store an unknown number of individual unique variables in the database, but he knows exactly what he wants to store, so creating a table schema that allows for unlimited numbers of variables named anything you want is confusing and error prone. The table OP wants will store 1 text string, the version number, lets not over complicate it.